# convert a character to a table in R

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I am trying to get a .csv file from an S3 bucket.
I am using

```
x = getFile()
```

from the RAmazonS3 and converting it to a character using

```
y=rawToChar(x).
```

I wish to convert y to a data table with the same structure as the csv file (2 columns) the lines sep is \n and the inner line sep is a ",".

**Code:**

```
table = rawToChar(getFile("bucket/file.csv"))
```

**Output:**

```
"\"id\",\"name\"\n\"12\",\"Member 12\"\n\"123\",\"Member 123\"\n\"1234\",\"Member 1234\"\n\"12345\....
```

And i wish it to be a 2 columns data.table/frame of the form:

```
  id                   name
  12              Member 12
  123             Member 123
  1234            Member 1234
  12345           Member 12345
```

Any suggestions on an efficient way to perform this conversion?

Any other (more useful) suggestions on how to retrieve csv files from an amazon S3 bucket to a table in R are more then welcome of course.

*I am using:

```
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
```

Any help in this issue would be appreciated, 
Thank you

Comment: `split` followed by `str_split_fixed` (stringr) should do it.

Comment: Just use `read.csv` as in `read.csv(text = 
'\"id\",\"name\"\n\"12\",\"Member 12\"\n\"123\",\"Member 123\"\n\"1234\",\"Member 1234\"')`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Have you modified the string by changing  `"` to `'`?  I copy/pasted the original string, and couldn't run it using `read.csv`, while your string gives the result.

Comment: @akrun, nope. I just wrapped it all up between two `'`. The reason you are not getting the correct result is because OP didn't provide the correct amount of rows. You need to remove the last `"12345\....`

Comment: Ok, I had `'"\"id\",\"name\"\n\"12\",\"Member 12\"\n\"123\",\"Member 123\"\n\"1234\",\"Member 1234\"'`

Comment: @akrun, the first `"` is probably comes from R `print`